# Enterprise Architect: How to add a TaggedValue to a package in C#

Tags: c#, enterprise-architect

How I can add a tagged value to a package in C#. The EA.Package has no tagged values like EA.Element.
But it is possible to add a tv via GUI, so I think that is general possible.

Solution (thx Geert):

```
protected EA.Element getElementByPackage(EA.Package eaPackage){
    return repository.GetElementByGuid(eaPackage.PackageGUID);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A package in the API is both a EA.Package as an EA.Element.
Use the package.Element to access the tagged values for a package.

Comment: Thx! It works. Short additional note: The key is the guid and not the id of the corresponding package.

Comment: You don't need all that code. The package object already contains the Element object. Just use eaPackage.Element